# Python Selenium: How to Handle Long Dynamic Table?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, indexoutofrangeexception

I have a website (private, sorry) that has a table (number of rows vary), that is long enough to not all be displayed on the screen without scrolling. I have the code to pull the text I need from each row but stops when the table is no longer visible (list index out of range). If I manually scroll, it updates the DOM so messes with my code. Anyone have any ideas how to handle this and properly loop through the entire table?

```
    table = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "*table ID*")))
    body = table.find_element_by_class_name("*class name*")
    tableText = body.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
    myList = [None]*rows
    for i in range (1,rows):
        myList[i-1] = tableText[i-1].text
```

About half way through the loop I get the IndexError: list index out of range.
I thought about whether running in headless mode would solve this but unfortunately can't because the site requires manual login (no html present at login screen).

Comment: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/18796/unable-to-scroll-down-to-bottom-of-div-with-data-loading-dynamically

Comment: The table itself has its own scroll bar in addition to the global browser scroller. This is what I would need to scroll but like I said, immediately changes the DOM so would be a mess maintining the for loop without stale elements. Also, I dont know Java so couldn't make sense of a lot of that. I appreciate the response though

Comment: Your question is incomplete. Nobody can see how site looks like, scrolls etc.

Comment: I understand that. As I cannot share the site, I'm not looking for someone to solve my exact issue for me but rather asking for ideas or if anyone has come across a similar issue that they resolved. For example, is there another way to access a tables entire contents without scrolling?